# Group homomorphism proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi : G \rightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism. Show that if $|G|$ is finite, then $|\phi[G]|$ is finite and is a divisor of $|G|$.

Comment: Understood. Not a homework question, just reading through my book and wondering how to solve. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: If $A$ is any finite set, and $f:A\to B$ is any surjection, then $B$ is finite, so the finiteness of $|\varphi[G]|$ is immediate. For the rest, use the fact that $\varphi[G]\cong G/\ker\varphi$, and $\ker\varphi$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Is it a requirement for every group homomorphism to be surjective?

Comment: @FortDover: No, and $\varphi$ may not map $G$ onto $G'$; but $\varphi$ definitely *does* map $G$ onto $\varphi[G]$, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note is the fibre of G mapped to the single element of $\phi[G]$ is actually a coset of the subgroup ker($\phi$) in G.
So the sketch of the proof is

- List item split the Group G into the cosets using the subgroup $H=ker(\phi)$
- List item
  Using the idea of lagrange theorem where $|G|$=number cosets$|H|$. Relate this theorem to the homomorphism $\phi$.

So for
\begin{eqnarray}
      \phi(x)=\phi(a)\\ \nonumber
      \phi^{-1}(a)\phi(x)=e'\nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
as $\phi$ is homomorphism $\phi^{-1}(a)=\phi(a^{-1})$
\begin{eqnarray}
      \phi^{-1}(a)\phi(x)=\phi(a^{-1}x)\\ \nonumber
      \phi(a^{-1}x)=e'\nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
so that $a^{-1}x=ker(\phi)$ which is exactly the left cosets of G. As this can be done for every element x in G to an element in G' by $\phi$ so that
\begin{eqnarray}
  \phi(a_1^{-1}x)&=e' \\
  \vdots \\
  \phi(a_N^{-1}x)&=e'& \\
\end{eqnarray}
This done for each coset to the opposing value $\phi(a_i)$ so is finite.
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{FiniteGroupCollapse2.eps}
{\caption{G}}
\end{figure}

\
We know from lagrange's theorem we know
\begin{equation}
   |G|=number cosets|H|  \nonumber
 \end{equation}
As shown in figure $\phi(x)=\phi(a)$ which is by definition  onto but may not be 1-1. This collapsing of x to a is measured by $ker(\phi)$ so that
\begin{equation}
  |G|=|ker(\phi)|||\phi(G)|
   \end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
   \frac{|G|}{|\phi(G)|}=|ker(\phi|
\end{equation}

As all index are $\in \mathbb{Z}$ $|\phi(G)|$ must be a divisor of $|G| $
\end{document}